# Parameter filter based on another parameter value selected in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a parameter region having values APAC,US.
I have another parameter department having values D1,D2,D3,D4.

Now If I select Region value as APAC ,below that  I have to show Department parameter value as D1 and D2 for the user.

If I select Region values as US , I have to show Department value as D3 and D4

I tried but my 2nd parameter is not filtering based on first parameter value selected.

Please suggest how to do.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvjV8.png)

Answer (score 0):

If Region and Department fields have mapping in data set, then use Filters instead of a parameter.

For Department Filter check the option "Only Relevant Values" in filter settings.

Hope this works!